# Urchin Integration with Asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, integration, urchin

I have a Asp.net WebSite.Where in i need to implement(Most Viewed,Most Shared and Most Downloaded) features.We decided to go with URCHIN for the same.I dunno how to start  and i googled a lot but did not find any resource regarding this.Can any one Suggest me some links or how to start with.

Waiting for your reply.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you decided to use URCHIN ,, have a good start here:
https://secure.urchin.com/helpwiki/en/Help_Center.html

then here for advanced issues:

https://secure.urchin.com/helpwiki/en/Data_API.html

Comment: Hi Alaaeddin.Thanks for the link.According to my knoweledge..Implementing Urchin is like using javascript of urchin and pass some tracking url to it.And this javascript will be called when a user click on some links..is it.Please Correct me if i am wrong as i am new to this.

Comment: According to my knoweledge..Implementing Urchin is like using javascript of urchin and pass some tracking url to it.And this javascript should be called when a user click on some links..is it.Please Correct me if i am wrong as i am new to this.Also tell me about that java script implementation.Some typo mistakes in above comment so re-edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Urchin generates reports by reading web server log files.  Create a Log Source in Urchin that specifies the location of your IIS logs, add the Log Source to a Profile, and you will see data in the reports.

Urchin Profiles have two options for tracking methods: UTM and IP+UA.  UTM requires JavaScript page tags, and IP+UA uses the existing data in your log files.  If you're new to Urchin, you probably don't have UTM code on your website so IP+UA is your best option for seeing data in the reports.